# Manage connections for multiple PivotTables and queries but one Access file

Tags: excel, ms-access, connection, odbc, pivot-table

I have to admit I go the traditional way of adding connections, I select the Data ribbon and select "from Access", browse to the file and select the query. I do this for each PivotTable and the underlying query. This results in multiple data connections which is a challenge when I relocate the Access db and multiple file paths need to be updated.

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: If the pivot tables are pointing to a common source data, then copy an existing pivot and adjust as needed, instead of creating a new one...

Comment: The pivot tables use different queries from the same access database as datasource, which require each a different odbc connection acccording to my basic understanding. I am missing a sophisticated connection manager. A first workaround that I found is to simply rename the access database. Then on refresh an old looking GUI pops-up providing the possibility to provide a new file path to a different access db. Works but is there no more sophisticated manager available in Access 2013 :-)?